# layout with fragment and framelayout replaced by another fragment and framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

**EDIT:**

So after the comments below, I revisted and realized what was hanging me up.

Imagine my client list and client details activity be started by :

```
public class ClientsMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //StudioTabOpenHelper db;
        setContentView(R.layout.main_client_activity);
    }
}
```

So this works great, starts up my main_client_Activity (defined in a layout below, and i call this activity when a button on my main screen is clicked):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClientsMainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Easy the issue is, the `ClientsMainActivity` does not call a OnCreateView or anything, just sets the layout to the layout that defines my Fragment, and my ListFragment.  This is fine cause I am not trying to pass anything into the `ClientsMainActivity`, but if I have a hypothetical activity like:

`SessionMainsActivity` that is called when they click on the session edit of a client, then I would not be calling the `SessionsMainActivity` the same way (starts activity that just sets to alayout), i would want that layout set as it defines how my fragments are split up.  But I would also want to pass in data to that and then to the subsequent fragments (like which session they clicked on to be editing/mucking with.

So I wonder if the above makes sense, I am sure its a simple thing I just cannot wrap my brain around.  I have no issues calling `FragmentActivitie`s from other fragments, they take up the whole screen but it works.  So I guess the big issue is that `ClientsMainActivity` is from some example I found online for doing recipes that shows you how to make multiple fragments to a screen.  The thing that gets me all that `FragmentActivity` does is sets the content view, to a layout that does all the work it seems, so that's why I cannot figure out how I would code it to do the same thing but let me pass in values to the fragments the layout defines etc...

**END EDIT**

So I am using this nice little tutorial here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

It has gotten me a long way and utilizing what they say to do for the main activity, and the fragment_layout.xml, I got a nice client list on the left (Thats a listfragment) and a details fragment on the right.

Then i added the ability to edit session information on a client (or edit client details) both of which were full screen fragments.  This worked great.

Now I decided my Session edit ui would best be served splitting the information up into two panes again.

This is not working as I thought, like I said I have a main_Activity that does this in the onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_client_activity);
}
```

with the `main_client_activity.xml` being defined in two layouts but the one for landscape tablets is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment class="com.viciousbytes.studiotab.subactivities.ClientListView"
        android:id="@+id/client_list" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/client_details" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This all works great!  In which case I handled everything else as a full screen activity that started its own fragment:

`EditSessionActivity`
`EditClientActiivyt`  both of which use getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction and I could pass information into it from the .newInstance call.

I had my `session_edit.xml` layout defined with buttons, textviews etc..and that was working great.  Thats what i loaded in my `SessionEdit` fragment "launched" by my `EditSessionActivity` But now since I want to split it apart I ran into a snag.  Above I defined a client_list and a client_details id, are these placeholders on my screen?  do I reference those when I wanna replace whats there with totally different fragments?

or do i build another fragment layout called something like fragment_session_layout which defines something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment class="com.viciousbytes.studiotab.subactivities.SessionEdit"
        android:id="@+id/session_edit" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/invoice_details" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry don't know what to title this on the tip of my tongue of what I am asking, basically how to get two panes of fragments twice over.  THe demo online shows how to do one (and a simple ListFragment at that).

I have done all the above and I just cannot figure out how to pass into the fragment the data I need, I was using this in my EditSessionActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int clientID = getIntent().getIntExtra(THE_SELECTED_CLIENT, -1);            
    int sessionID = getIntent().getIntExtra(SELECTED_SESSION,-1);
    SessionEdit edits = SessionEdit.newInstance(this.getBaseContext(), false, clientID, sessionID);
    mUIListener = (OnUpdateUI)edits;
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, edits).commit();
}
```

that worked, but to try to adhere to the earlier fragment example, i assumed my `EditSessionActivit`y was sorta like making another `MainActivity` (cause it has two panels in it like the main one).  so I recoded the `onCreate` in `EditSessionActivity` with this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_session_fullview);
}
```

Which after fighting in my EditSession fragment dealing with the onCreateView, I got this to finally work but couldn't pass in the data cause there is no instantiation of the object using like the previous `onCreate` which had the `edits=SessionEdit.newInstance(...)`

So is it good practice to be doing the other fragment layout that has two pains in it and starting that up when the right action is triggered.  Or is one supposed to replace the two already created fragments?? from my `main_client_activity.xml` somehow?

Comment: I have the same "problem" now, I have got 2 listfragments in the view and I'm changing dinamically after a row is selected.I think a lot which one is the better but I dont think this is the best way that I used.

Comment: The examples for these fragments online are usually sufficient for simple cases, but any more than that and you are on your own.  Hopefully someone has a good suggestion.

Comment: I aggree with you, this tutorials good for basic situations and if someone wants to create complicated UI with fragments he needs to think a lot :D

Comment: I don't mind thinking I just want to know the right way to do things as to not create house-of-cards software in the future :)  I am now even wrestling with a DialogFragment I created using their tutorial, it works but comes up as its own UI "page", not as a dialog "hovering" on top of other stuff, not sure what I did wrong.  My date/time dialog fragmetns work great though *Shrug*

Answer (score 3):

I assume editing clients and editing sessions are two distinct activities. When you switch from "editing clients" to "editing sessions" mode, both the "list" and "details" panes would change?

I would go with two layout files, instead of trying to reuse the same layout and reload fragments in it.

If you tried to reuse the same layout, you would have to:

- Change `@+id/invoice_details` to something like `@+id/right_pane`. Otherwise it would look confusing to load something related to sessions into "invoice_details" placeholder.
- replace fragment definition with another `FrameLayout` and load either `ClientListView` or `SessionListView` (or however it's called) fragment there at runtime.

This would add more complexity than having another layout xml file in my opinion.

So

- Take your existing code that works with client list and client details
- Duplicate all involved parts, and change what needs to be changed so it's now session list and session details
- Remove duplication where it's easy to do (common functions go to utility classes, common layout elements to layout includes). Leave the things that are hard to de-duplicate as-is.
- Re-evaluate later, when you have more fragments, more layouts and more experience.

**UPDATE, about two different approaches fragments can be embedded in activity**

As the Android documentation states, there are two main ways you can get a fragment to show up in your activity:

- declare the fragment in layout's XML file (`<fragment class=.... />`)
- put a placeholder `FrameLayout` in layout's XML file and load fragment at runtime

First approach is fine when fragment doesn't need to receive any arguments. Like, for example, if the logic to retrieve single and only list of clients is hardcoded in fragment's code.

Second approach lets you pass arguments to the fragment, and therefore is appropriate for "details drilldown" type of fragments.

From updated question I understand that,

- each client has a separate list of sessions
- the components in play are: `EditSessionActivity` that hosts two fragments, one for displaying list of sessions, another for displaying session details

If that's correct, then indeed you'd need to load both fragments programmatically because both needs parameters to be passed to. So your layout would have two `FrameLayout`s. The `EditSessionActivity` would start with getting some parameters from intent ("which list of sessions are we working with?"), and load "list of sessions" fragment with these parameters. When user selects list item in that fragment, the other fragment would be loaded with session details.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I am going to get to this.  I think the biggest issue is the way my layout code worked is that one side was a ListFragment, the other side was just a FrameLayout.  So in my session stuff I want two FrameLayouts (or at this point would they be fragments?) I think I also was confused on to how to pass some complex objects (my own data objects) over to the FragmentActivity in this case, maybe just make it serializable?  I havne't looked at this in a while so I will double check to see which part was hanging me up specifically and repost here.

Comment: If session stuff is analogous to clients (list of sessions on left, session details on right) then I think your layout would also be similar: ListFragment on left, FrameLayout on right. When an item is selected on lefthand list, a fragment for editing session details would be loaded  into FrameLayout. As for passing data around:  either serializable (parcelable) objects, or global state. Or, if the objects come from something like local sqlite database, you could pass around database IDs, and read your objects from DB as/when needed.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it addresses your issue.

Comment: so my EditSessionActivity would load that framelayout content view which has two framelayouts defined (and I programmatically) build the fragments, would that be in another fragment activity or in EditSessionActivity would I build and load the two fragments?

Comment: Yah I am confused I guess by how to load the two frame layouts?  and load the fragments progamatically all from the main `EditSessionActivity FragmentActivity`.

Comment: I like your theory about the two approaches to instantiate a Fragment, one is useful if you don't have to pass parameters around and the other when you do, I kind of agree with it, but I wonder if anyone thinks the same, or there is another way to pass parameters to a fragment